# What's the recommended way to get winhttp.h?

Tags: c++, windows, proxy, sdk, winhttp

Our application uses libcurl for HTTP, and we want to get access to Internet Explorer's proxy settings. An earlier Stack Overflow question [recommends that we use `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser` and `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202547/how-do-i-find-out-the-browsers-proxy-settings).

Unfortunately, the `winhttp.h` header does not appear to be included with our copies either Visual C++ 2005 or Visual Studio 2008. Apparently, [it's possible to download an updated Platform SDK and install it in Visual C++ 2005](http://bbulkow.blogspot.com/2006/04/winhttp-and-visual-studio-2005-howto.html), but it's a pretty painful process, and it doesn't necessarily work with newer versions of Visual Studio.

Is there a good, well-supported way to access the WinHTTP 5.1 APIs from C++? Or should we avoid using these APIs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best, well-supported way to access the WinHTTP 5.1 APIs from C++ is via the Windows SDK (new name for the Platform SDK) and using those APIs you mentioned.

The article you linked to suggests that installing the SDK is difficult - the good news is its an old article from 2006 and things are much easier these days. Just do the following:

1. Download the latest SDK ISO image from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) - don't worry about it being called the "SDK for Windows Server 2008", it's also for Server 2003, XP and Vista.
2. Burn to DVD
3. Run the setup.exe on the DVD, select full installation and let it run for 1/2 hour or so.
4. After installation, goto Start -> Programs -> Microsoft Windows SDK -> Visual Studio Registration -> **Integrate Windows SDK with Visual Studio 2005**

You may even be prompted to run the integration tool during installation - it's been a while since I installed it so I can't recall exactly.

The Visual C++ compiler will then be able to find winhttp.h and winhttp.lib in the appropriate folders.

**Update** As usual things are never as simple as they should be. EMK has pointed out that the Windows SDK Configuration Tool doesn't work properly with Visual Studio 2008 (any version) and crashes after installing Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Details and workarounds are reported [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/62b7d1a6-5210-4f1e-8fc5-a06193edce22/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/7d0eafe5-477b-40cc-85a1-cd6296c6b745).

Comment: Thanks! Is the full installation actually necessary, or could we get away with only installing (for example) the relevant C++ parts?

Comment: I forget what options there are - you can probably get away with just the Win32 headers and libraries. However, I normally install absolutely everything, since disk space is cheap but presumably your time (to figure out what components you need) is not.

Comment: Fair enough! We need to install it on a lot of machines, so I figured it might be worth figuring out which components we actually need. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: To make this work, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/62b7d1a6-5210-4f1e-8fc5-a06193edce22/ and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/7d0eafe5-477b-40cc-85a1-cd6296c6b745 . Could you please link to these pages in your answer?

Comment: EMKs links helped me when I currently in the age of Visual Studio 2015 had to go back and build something with vc8 that links to winhttp.lib. First edit the registry to fix the bad entries and then run the configuration tool to set vs2005 and vs2008 to use 6.0a SDK.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone comes across this post and is curious about the minimal components that can be installed to get winhttp, installing Microsoft Windows Core SDK > Build Environment > Build Environment (x86 32-bit) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely don't need the whole SDK
Just download the right part, see MSDN for choices.

Comment: I agree you don't *need* the whole thing, but for many people figuring out the right part is more expensive than just installing all of it.