# How to build "Auto Detect Proxy Settings" In Windows and in Mac

Tags: c++, windows, macos, networking, proxy

What are the steps to implement that feature in 1) Windows and 2) in Mac? I went through these, still I am not very clear! I am using C/C++ in Windows and in Mac. So, Win API or Mac API will be enough.

I am also confused because Mac Firefox has also has a option "Use system proxy settings", which is not present in Windows Firefox.

These are some similar questions:

LINK-1: [Programmatically detect system-proxy settings on Windows XP with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068212/programitcally-detect-system-proxy-settings-on-windows-xp-with-python)

LINK-2: [How does Windows actually detect LAN (proxy) settings when using Automatic Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191023/how-does-windows-actually-detect-lan-proxy-settings-when-using-automatic-config)

According the this [Wiki WPAD article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol), we should traverse in this sequence:

- http://wpad.branch.example.com/wpad.dat
- http://wpad.example.com/wpad.dat
- http://wpad.com/wpad.dat

But LINK-1 says "`GET http://wpad/wpad.dat`" is enough. Which one should I follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I using [librproxy](http://code.google.com/p/libproxy). That solved this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you use [`SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(NULL)`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html) and query the resulting dictionary for the information you need. See [QA1234](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1234.html) for an example.

On Windows the linked questions should get you where you need. You might want to add where you got stuck.

Comment: Here is a followup that shows how to retrieve the username and password from the keychain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636639/how-can-i-get-the-username-for-a-proxy-host-from-keychain/15085066#15085066