# Allow access of application based on ip, or proxy network coverage

Tags: ios, authentication, proxy

I have a reader application and we are customizing the reader to a certain institution to allow the user to use the application and read from its content. I have to verify whether he is under a certain proxy coverage and that he is logged in to that proxy.

I personally have very little experience with networking and proxy, therefore I would like to ask, whether this is doable and if so, what is the best way to approach it?

In case this is doable will Apple accept it and how can Apple team test the functionality?

I have come over this solution, but I'm not sure if this is what I need: 
[How can I get the username for a proxy host from KeyChain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636639/how-can-i-get-the-username-for-a-proxy-host-from-keychain)

Comment: Do you need to check for a known range of IPs (proxies)? In that case, why don't you just check the public IP of the user against a list of allowed IPs (proxies) on your server, and if the IP isn't known (whitelisted) no access is granted? Might also work the other way around. ip2location.com has gigantic proxy lists.

Comment: No since I'm checking mobile devices I'm not sure I can check ips, I just need to check whether the user is currently logged in to the hosting proxy.

Comment: Wouldn't the proxy change your public IP to the proxy one though? I don't do iOS developement but I'd find it VERY strange if there was no way to get the public WAN IP. It's definitely possible since apps like speedtest.net do it.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I will try using ip address and see where I get.

Comment: @confetti I have used your advice for ip address and it seems very good solution would you kindly submit your suggestion so I may accept it. thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! I left my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go and use the public WAN IP address of the device to check for proxy usage.

Knowing the IPs of the proxy, I would put those in a whitelist, stored preferably on an external server which will by queried by the app instead of hardcoding it into the app in case a proxy server changes its IP.

On every app start I would then get the public IP of the device, which will be one of the proxy IPs if the user is using the proxy. So you can simple compare those IPs and if they match you know the user is using a proxy.

If you don't know the specific IPs of the proxy there are plenty of services available which can determine if an IP belongs to a proxy and which type of proxy it is. [IP2location](https://www.ip2location.com/) is one of the many sites which offer such things.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would like to check the global proxy settings.
It's possible to do in this way:

```
NSDictionary *proxySettings = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
NSString *type = proxySettings[(id)kCFProxyTypeKey];
NSString *hostname = proxySettings[(id)kCFProxyHostNameKey];
NSNumber *port = proxySettings[(id)kCFProxyPortNumberKey];
NSString *username = proxySettings[(id)kCFProxyUsernameKey];
NSString *password = proxySettings[(id)kCFProxyPasswordKey];
```

Then you can do checks that you may need to verify the proxy. For other possible keys and values in `proxySettings` dictionary you can check `CFProxySupport.h` file.

You can store some JSON file on your server that is behind your proxy, where you'll describe configuration of the proxy that you'll verify, e.g.

```
{
    "type":"https",
    "host":"my_awesome_proxy.edu",
    "port":8080
}
```

At the app start, your app will first download this file, and then check that it's behind the proxy that is specified in the file.
This will make your app independent of the changes in proxy settings in future, so you won't need to submit the app to the app store with another hardcoded proxy values for verification.

During app review, Apple may ask you to provide them access credentials to test the app. So, at the time of review, your proxy should be globally accessible and have some test credentials configured, which you'll forward to Apple.

P.S.
The approach to verify proxy is very insecure, and VPN connection into university's intranet sounds much more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.