# Using system proxy in NSURLSession - unable to get challenge for setting credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, networking, nsurlsession

I've got system proxy configuration which include user credentials (name+password), and I'd like to use it with my `NSURLSession` object to send http messages in macOS or iOS applications.

From `connectionProxyDictionary` documentation, I haven't set this value to get what I need :

> The default value is NULL, which means that tasks use the default system settings`

My http message goes through the server. However, it appears that the packet doesn't have `Proxy-Authorization` and I get `Cache Access Denied` from the proxy, although in system configuration the credentials are well set.

So I need to explicitly set the Proxy-Authorization header according to the global proxy configuration `SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies`. Perhaps there's a way to avoid it and let the NSURLSession take the credentials automatically. ?

I've found out that I should provide those credentials after getting proper challenge. However, this challenge never occur (my callback doesn't get called).