# How to set proxy in Windows with Python?

Tags: python, windows, proxy, registry

How can I get the current Windows' browser proxy setting, as well as set them to a value?

I know I can do this by looking in the registry at `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer`, but I'm looking, if it is possible, to do this without messing directly with the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urllib module automatically retrieves settings from registry when no proxies are specified as a parameter or in the environment variables

> In a Windows environment, if no proxy
>   environment variables are set, proxy
>   settings are obtained from the
>   registry’s Internet Settings section.

See the documentation of urllib module referenced in the earlier post.

To set the proxy I assume you'll need to use the pywin32 module and modify the registry directly.

Comment: Manual registry fiddling, it is.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you are using uses `urlopen` under the hood you an set the `http_proxy` environment variable to have it picked up.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) here for more  info.

Comment: I also need to set the proxy system wide (for `Internet Explorer` and other `Microsoft` software), not just my application. Anyway, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser as stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202547/how-do-i-find-out-the-browsers-proxy-settings)

There's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-apis-with-python) with examples of [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), the Python for Windows extensions.