# Change browser proxy settings from Python?

Tags: python, browser, proxy, settings

I have written a program that relies on a proxy to function. I now need a script that will check to see if the browser is set to use the right proxy, and if not, change it to use it. I need this implemented for as many browsers as possible, but is only required for ***Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari and Opera***. I am not even sure how to go about this, but it is for a project for work that will be due in a few days. If anyone can help or lend advice, I would greatly appreciate it!

I am programming on:
 
MS Windows XP
Python 2.6

Comment: Discussion on *reading* proxy settings here that you might be interested in:
http://old.nabble.com/using-windows-wide-proxy-settings-td20822378.html

I'm not sure I'd go around automatically changing users' proxy settings though (unless it's meant to be some kind of configuration shortcut?)

Also, there's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201771/how-to-set-proxy-with-python

Comment: Yeah, I had seen those. I am looking for some example code or something. Thanks though.

Comment: Would the pythonwin extension be able to help with this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Windows stores its system wide proxy in the registry, look in the the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`. You can use the Python _winreg module to change it (or just winreg if you use Python 3). Here is a sample code

```
import _winreg as winreg

INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

def set_key(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

set_key('ProxyEnable', 1)
set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost
set_key('ProxyServer', u'X.X.X.X:8080')
```

To disable it you can just need to set ProxyEnable key to 0:

```
set_key('ProxyEnable', 0)
```

After the script runs the browsers will still have the old proxy stored in-memory, so you need to restart them so they can re-read the new proxy settings from the registry. I found this to be very annoying so I converted [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020363/how-to-change-global-windows-proxy-using-c-net-with-immediate-effect) to Python.

```
import ctypes

INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37
INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39

internet_set_option = ctypes.windll.Wininet.InternetSetOptionW

internet_set_option(0, self.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, 0, 0)
internet_set_option(0, self.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, 0, 0)
```

This refreshes the Windows settings so all you have to do is hit F5 in your browser in order to it grab the new proxy settings.

I've written a small script to switch my proxy on or off, the source in on Bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/canassa/switch-proxy

This should work with any browser that uses the Windows system-wide proxy (e.g.: Chrome, IE). Some browsers like Firefox uses a internal proxy settings. If you want to change these you will have figure out where they store their settings and write code to change it.

Comment: 9 years later if someone is wondering ,it says in the `_winreg` documentation, it has been renamed to `winreg` in Python 3.0

Comment: @Rishav Yes, the answer mentions that :)

Comment: I used pyinstaller to make an executable, but the executable doesn't change proxy settings. Are there special privileges I need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to @Cesar Canassa, but there is a small problem, you should always refresh ***after*** you change the setting, otherwise the changes you just made in winreg will be discarded when you refresh. So it should be like this.

```
import ctypes

INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37
INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39

internet_set_option = ctypes.windll.Wininet.InternetSetOptionW

internet_set_option(0, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, 0, 0)
internet_set_option(0, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

***On*** or ***Off*** - ***IE Proxy*** (for Python 3.9):

```
import winreg
import ctypes

# On or Off - IE Proxy   (On=1 or Off=0)
proxyOnOff = 0

# Modification
INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
_, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, 'ProxyEnable')
winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, 'ProxyEnable', 0, reg_type, proxyOnOff)

# Implementation
INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37
INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39
internet_set_option = ctypes.windll.Wininet.InternetSetOptionW
internet_set_option(0, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, 0, 0)
internet_set_option(0, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, 0, 0)

# Read state - ProxyEnable
proxyEnable = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, 'ProxyEnable')[0]
print(f"proxyEnable = {proxyEnable}")

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```