# Change/Edit the proxy settings on windows using python

Tags: windows

I'am trying to edit/configure a proxy server using python on windows using below code.
But i get an error. Need help !!

```
import winreg

INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

def set_key(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

set_key('ProxyEnable', 1)
set_key('ProxyServer', u'192.168.0.5:3128')
```

Comment: Am using Windows 8
I get the below Error

>>> set_key('ProxyServer', u'192.168.0.5:3128')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in set_key
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: (Don't have enough reputation to flag as duplicate)

[Change browser proxy settings from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050262/change-browser-proxy-settings-from-python)

Comment: I was referring to the same above link for my use case.
But, the last line in the code gave error as i reported.
want to get rid of this
Thanks

Comment: Can i get some help in getting this work ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to query for a key that does not exist yet. You need to create the key in your registry.
Setting the value direclty also creates the key.

```
INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, "ProxyServer", 0, winreg.REG_SZ, "your server address")
```