# C# .Net 2.0 Automatic Configuration of proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, configure

I am working on a project to download files using .Net c# 2.0 SP1. One of the requirements of the project is to not seek any proxy details and automatically detect this from IE etc.

Now i haven't worked with proxy before and hence i am a bit baffled. After hours of searching google, msdn etc, i have come across the following article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc300743.aspx#S3

Now i am totally confused how to do this? Can someone please help me with an easier implementation or guide me please?

Sorry once again if i sound silly, but i haven't worked with .Net proxies and hence I am struggling.

This is for C# Winforms and hence i cannot do this in web.config.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 2.0 will automatically using the proxy settings from IE by default; however, there is an extra configuration step required to use the default proxy credentials saved in IE. To enable this, ensure that the following section appears in your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
    </system.net>
```

For a full description of the  element, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx). For more complicated HTTP Proxy scenarios, see [Using HTTP Proxy Servers](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/01/using_http_proxy_servers.html).

Comment: I should have mentioned this that i need to do this for winforms.

Comment: I am looking for some C# code possible similar to C code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202547/how-do-i-find-out-the-browsers-proxy-settings/2238761#2238761

Comment: @Manish haven't tested it yet but maybe this might help: "pac file should have proper content type (`Content-type: application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig`)", more [Using Proxy Automatic Configuration from IE Settings in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13562345/1027198).