# Using Proxy Automatic Configuration from IE Settings in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, pac

I'm having trouble getting Proxy Automatic Configuration (PAC) in IE options to work as expected using .Net WebRequest.

According to this article:
[Proxy Detection
Take the Burden Off Users with Automatic Configuration in .NET](http://web.archive.org/web/20120329222856/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc300743.aspx)

The system proxy should be set by default with to each WebRequest.

That's how the proxy.js pac file looks like:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  return "PROXY ProxyServerName:3118; DIRECT;";
}
```

I also took a look at this post: [How should I set the default proxy to use default credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299940/how-should-i-set-the-default-proxy-to-use-default-credentials)

Which suggests to add this in the app.config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Adding this did not help.

I created a small console application just to test this out.. here it is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    try
    {               
        String resolvedAddress = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://www.google.com")).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Proxy for address is: " + resolvedAddress);

        Uri m_URLToTest = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        request = WebRequest.Create(m_URLToTest) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string message = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Exception");
    }

}
```

The output:
Proxy for address is http://www.google.com

instead of Proxy for address is ProxyServerName:3118

It happens only when using auto configuration script...

Did I miss anything? Please help!

Comment: The issue was with the mime-type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution!

It is really important that the mime type of the PAC file would be: [Content-type: application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig]

Other mime types might not work.

Make sure using fiddler2 (with cache disabled) that the mime type is appropriate. 
Some configurations might show Content-Type: text/plain which is bad.

Comment: Also make sure that the configuration file extension is .pac

Comment: You can accept your own question. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and it won't show up in list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checked `Internet (Client & Server)` and `Private Networks (Client & Server)` capabilities in `Package.appxmanifest`.

[image: See this]

[[Source]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b57c6625-84ca-4281-8de2-14311014aecf/consume-web-services-from-metro-apps-c?forum=winappswithcsharp)