# Web proxy in pac file and error

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

My question is regarding the pac file and .net application to connect using it.

Basically I have an HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, when I create an HttpWebRequest, because i'm behind a proxy i have to use proxy to connect to outside world. So in my proxy settings i have to use PAC file to obtain the correct adress, but when i use pac file i get a following error:

```
{"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}
```

Innerexception:

```
{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}
```

I'm sure it has something to do with a wrong use of PAC file, because for example if i take a proxy ip adress from a pac file i can connect, but of course i would like to use pac file as rule to connect to internet.

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);                request.Method = "GET";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://.../proxy.pac");                
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(UsrData.username, UsrData.password);
            proxy.Credentials = networkCredential;

            request.Proxy = proxy;

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
              ....
            }
           }
```

For request here is a short version of pac:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
if ( shExpMatch(host,"bbcs.companyname.com"))
        return  "PROXY 158.169.10.11:8010; "+
                "PROXY 158.169.132.11:8010";


if ( !shExpMatch(host,"*.*") ||
      shExpMatch(host,"intragate*.compname.com") ||
      shExpMatch(host,"127.0.0.*") ||
      shExpMatch(host,"10.*.*.*") ||
      shExpMatch(host,"192.168.*") ||
      shExpMatch(host,"139.191.*") ||
   )
        return "DIRECT";


if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "158.166.0.0","255.255.128.0") ||
        isInNet(myIpAddress(), "158.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0"))
                return  "PROXY 158.165.132.13:8010; " +
                                "PROXY 158.165.5.11:8010";


else 
        return  "PROXY 158.169.10.11:8010; " +
                "PROXY 158.169.132.11:8010";
}
```

Any idea what do i miss?

Using a PacTester and surfing to some url i get the return of PROXY + ip, can it be cause of the return word PROXY? also the itp is not fully correct path not like "http://ip..."

Comment: Could you paste you proxy PAC script to check syntax?

Comment: it is very large file ... and it works for sure, as it is used across all the company

Comment: Looks like its proxy problem. Could You try connect to some transparent proxy?

Comment: If you paste your http:// proxy file in internet explorer doest it try to download the file?. Just to check your proxy pac url is correct

Comment: yes it does, download, btw i updated post with the short version of pac :)

Comment: Old question, but perhaps this Question might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552227/using-proxy-automatic-configuration-from-ie-settings-in-net