# How can I make Invoke-RestMethod use the default web proxy?

Tags: rest, powershell

The following works fine on my machine which does not use a web proxy.

```
return Invoke-RestMethod 
   -Uri $server$url 
   -ContentType $contentType 
   -Headers $headers 
   -Method $method 
   -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Note: the `$server$url` is an *https* address, something like *https://somewhere.example.com/api/data*

Now I'm trying to get it to work in a corporate environment but I am getting a 401 error.

I think this is because there is a corporate proxy which is defined with a proxy.pac file. I have confirmed I can get to the `$server$url` URI from Internet Explorer. What do I need to do to get the `Invoke-RestMethod` command to work using the same settings?

I have tried adding the `-proxy` parameter

```
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

return Invoke-RestMethod 
    -Uri $server$url 
    -ContentType $contentType 
    -Headers $headers 
    -Method $method 
    -UseDefaultCredentials 
    -Proxy $proxy 
    -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
```

but the -Proxy parameter is expecting a URI not an `IWebProxy` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Once incorrect address is provided the command no longer works and returns the address provided instead of the proxy address.. 
Do not use this:
Using the code snippet in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13552227/3065397), I am able to retrieve the proxy uri from PowerShell as such:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy([uri]("http://www.google.com"))
```

Use this instead:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy("http://www.google.com")
```

It still returns the provided URI (or throws) when the uri is invalid, but once correct uri is provided is starts working again.

Comment: Hmm... in my case the URL is an https address. Then `GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy()` returns _The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme_.

Comment: For some reason after running this command `[System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy("https://www.google.com")` my original code started working again.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer got me started. Here's the full version

```
$headers = @{"X-My-ApiKey"=$apiKey}
$contentType = "application/json"

$proxyUri = [Uri]$null
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
if ($proxy)
{
    $proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
    $proxyUri = $proxy.GetProxy("$server$url")
}

if ("$proxyUri" -ne "$server$url")
{
    Write-Host "Using proxy: $proxyUri"
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $server$url -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Method $method -UseDefaultCredentials -Proxy $proxyUri -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials
}
else
{
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $server$url -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Method $method -UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

Comment: In my specific case, all I did was add the parameter `-UseDefaultCredentials`, and bingo.